# Fiscal Year issue in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm using sql server, our fiscal year starts on 10/1/

I would like to get fiscal quarter and year in a query.

this is the query i'm using:

```sql
with cte
as (select CASE_DSCR
         , DATE_IMPOSED
         , AMENDED_ACTN_CD_DSCR
         , datepart(quarter, DATE_IMPOSED) as "Quarter"
         , datepart(year, DATE_IMPOSED)    as "Year"
    from dbo.TblCaseDetail
    where DATE_IMPOSED
    between '2018 october 1' and '2021 June 30'
    and casetype = 'Felony'
    and Conviction = 1
    )
select cte.CASE_DSCR
     , cte.AMENDED_ACTN_CD_DSCR
     , 'Quarter ' + cast(cte.Quarter as varchar(15)) + ' ' + cast(cte.Year as varchar(15)) as "Quarter"
from cte
order by cte.DATE_IMPOSED;
```

I would like to get the fiscal year and quarter in the results:

like this (but with the right fiscal data)
[image]

Comment: Subtract 9 months from the date and now you have the fiscal year as a calendar year value.

Comment: We added datetrunc to give you a way to just get the (calendar year) quarter from a date directly.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the dates given in between?

```
with cte
as (select CASE_DSCR
         , DATE_IMPOSED
         , AMENDED_ACTN_CD_DSCR
         , datepart(quarter, DATE_IMPOSED) as "Quarter"
         , datepart(year, DATE_IMPOSED)    as "Year"
    from dbo.TblCaseDetail
    where DATE_IMPOSED
    between '2022 october 1' and '2022 June 30'
    and casetype = 'Felony'
    and Conviction = 1
    )
select cte.CASE_DSCR
     , cte.AMENDED_ACTN_CD_DSCR
     , 'Quarter ' + cast(cte.Quarter as varchar(15)) + ' ' + cast(cte.Year as varchar(15)) as "Quarter"
from cte
order by cte.DATE_IMPOSED;
```